# Pandas: using groupby and nunique taking time into account

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in this form:

```
A    B    time
1    2    2019-01-03
1    3    2018-04-05
1    4    2020-01-01
1    4    2020-02-02
```

where A and B contain some integer identifiers.
I want to measure the number of different identifiers each A has interacted with. To do this I usually simply do

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique()
```

I now have to do a slightly different thing: each identifier has a date assigned (different for each identifier), that splits its interactions in 2 parts: the ones happening before that date, and the ones happening after that date. The same operation previously done (counting number of unique B interacted with ) needs to be done for both parts separately.

For example, if the date for A=1 was 2018-07-01, the output would be

```
A    before    after
1    1         2
```

In the real data, A contains millions of different identifiers, each with its unique date assigned.

EDITED
To be more clear I added a line to df. I want to count the number of different values of B each A interacts with before and after the date

Answer (score 1):

I would convert `A` into dates, compare those with `df['time']` and then `groupby().value_counts()`:

```
(df['A'].map(date_dict)
    .gt(df['time'])
    .groupby(df['A'])
    .value_counts()
    .unstack()
    .rename({False:'after',True:'before'}, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   after  before
A               
1      2       1
```

Comment: I think this would not work if different identifiers share the same date from date_dict, am I right? In my case this is likely to happen

Comment: Did you try? It should work since we do `groupby(df['A'])`.

Comment: ok I just tried, actually there is another mistake. In my question I ask for a behavior like nunique. Value counts instead, and I suspect the mapping to dates, does not take the unique values of B. I am not asking for the simple count of times A appears before or after the date, but the number of different unique B it interacts with before and after

Comment: I solved it myself thanks to your hint. I just created a new column with your map and gt, then groupbyed A and the new column, using nunique on B. Will post a complete answer myself